# Calculate mean of all groups except the current group

Tags: r, group-by, average, mean

I have a data frame with two grouping variables, 'mkt' and 'mdl', and some values 'pr':

```
df <- data.frame(mkt = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 mdl = c('a','a','b','b','b','a','b','a','b'),
                 pr = c(120,120,110,110,145,130,145,130, 145))

df

  mkt mdl  pr
1   1   a 120
2   1   a 120
3   1   b 110
4   1   b 110
5   2   b 145
6   2   a 130
7   2   b 145
8   2   a 130
9   2   b 145
```

Within each 'mkt', the mean 'pr' for each 'mdl' should be calculated as the mean of 'pr' of all other 'mdl' in the same 'mkt', *except* the current 'mdl'.

For example, for the group defined by `mkt == 1` and `mdl == a`, the 'avgother' is calculated as the average of 'pt' for `mkt == 1` (same 'mkt') and `mdl == b` (all other 'mdl' than the current group `a`).

Desired result:

```
#   mkt mdl  pr avgother
# 1   1   a 120      110
# 2   1   a 120      110
# 3   1   b 110      120
# 4   1   b 110      120
# 5   2   b 145      130
# 6   2   a 130      145
# 7   2   b 145      130
# 8   2   a 130      145
# 9   2   b 145      130
```

Answer (score 1):

First get the average of each `mkt` and `mdl` values and for each `mkt` exclude the current value and get the average of remaining values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_by(mkt, mdl) %>%
  summarise(avgother = mean(pr)) %>%
  mutate(avgother = map_dbl(row_number(), ~mean(avgother[-.x]))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  inner_join(df, by = c('mkt', 'mdl'))

#    mkt mdl   avgother    pr
#  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 a          110   120
#2     1 a          110   120
#3     1 b          120   110
#4     1 b          120   110
#5     2 a          145   130
#6     2 a          145   130
#7     2 b          130   145
#8     2 b          130   145
#9     2 b          130   145
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`, calculate sum and length by 'mkt'. Then, within each mkt-mdl group, calculate mean as `(mkt sum - group sum) / (mkt length - group length)`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , `:=`(s = sum(pr), n = .N), by = mkt]
df[ , avgother := (s - sum(pr)) / (n - .N), by = .(mkt, mdl)]
df[ , `:=`(s = NULL, n = NULL)]
#    mkt mdl  pr avgother
# 1:   1   a 120      110
# 2:   1   a 120      110
# 3:   1   b 110      120
# 4:   1   b 110      120
# 5:   2   b 145      130
# 6:   2   a 130      145
# 7:   2   b 145      130
# 8:   2   a 130      145
# 9:   2   b 145      130
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider base R with multiple `ave` calls for different level grouping calculation using the decomposed version of mean with `sum / count`:

```r
df <- within(df, {
      avgoth <- (ave(pr, mkt, FUN=sum) - ave(pr, mkt, mdl, FUN=sum)) /
                  (ave(pr, mkt, FUN=length) - ave(pr, mkt, mdl, FUN=length))
})

df
#   mkt mdl  pr avgoth
# 1   1   a 120    110
# 2   1   a 120    110
# 3   1   b 110    120
# 4   1   b 110    120
# 5   2   b 145    130
# 6   2   a 130    145
# 7   2   b 145    130
# 8   2   a 130    145
# 9   2   b 145    130
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is another `data.table` approach which uses *grouping by each i*, i.e.,  join and aggregate simultaneously.

For demonstration, an enhanced sample dataset is used which has a third market with 3 products:

```
df <- data.frame(mkt = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 mdl = c('a','a','b','b','b','a','b','a','b', letters[1:3]),
                 pr = c(120,120,110,110,145,130,145,130, 145, 1:3))

library(data.table)
mdt <- setDT(df)[, .(mdl, s = sum(pr), .N), by = .(mkt)]
df[mdt, on = .(mkt, mdl), avgother := (sum(pr) - s) / (.N - N), by = .EACHI][]
```

> ```
>     mkt mdl  pr avgother
>  1:   1   a 120    110.0
>  2:   1   a 120    110.0
>  3:   1   b 110    120.0
>  4:   1   b 110    120.0
>  5:   2   b 145    130.0
>  6:   2   a 130    145.0
>  7:   2   b 145    130.0
>  8:   2   a 130    145.0
>  9:   2   b 145    130.0
> 10:   3   a   1      2.5
> 11:   3   b   2      2.0
> 12:   3   c   3      1.5
> ```

The temporay table `mdt` contains the sum and count of prices within each `mkt` but replicated for each product `mdl` within the market:

```
mdt
```

> ```
>     mkt mdl   s N
>  1:   1   a 460 4
>  2:   1   a 460 4
>  3:   1   b 460 4
>  4:   1   b 460 4
>  5:   2   b 695 5
>  6:   2   a 695 5
>  7:   2   b 695 5
>  8:   2   a 695 5
>  9:   2   b 695 5
> 10:   3   a   6 3
> 11:   3   b   6 3
> 12:   3   c   6 3
> ```

Having `mkt` *and* `mdl` in `mdt` allows for *grouping by each i* (`by = .EACHI`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which computes `avgother` directly by subsetting `pr` values which do *not* belong to the actual value of `mdl` before computing the averages.

This is quite different to the other answers posted so far which justifies to post this as a separate answer, IMHO.

```
# enhanced sample dataset covering more corner cases
df <- data.frame(mkt = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4),
                 mdl = c('a','a','b','b','b','a','b','a','b', letters[1:3],'d'),
                 pr = c(120,120,110,110,145,130,145,130, 145, 1:3, 9))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, avgother := sapply(mdl, function(m) mean(pr[m != mdl])), by = mkt][]
```

> ```
>     mkt mdl  pr avgother
>  1:   1   a 120    110.0
>  2:   1   a 120    110.0
>  3:   1   b 110    120.0
>  4:   1   b 110    120.0
>  5:   2   b 145    130.0
>  6:   2   a 130    145.0
>  7:   2   b 145    130.0
>  8:   2   a 130    145.0
>  9:   2   b 145    130.0
> 10:   3   a   1      2.5
> 11:   3   b   2      2.0
> 12:   3   c   3      1.5
> 13:   4   d   9      NaN
> ```

#### Difference between approaches

The other answers share more or less the same approach (although implemented in different manners)

1. compute sums and counts of `pr` for each `mkt`
2. compute sums and counts of `pr`for each `mkt` and `mdl`
3. subtract mkt/mdl sums and counts from mkt sums and counts
4. compute `avgother`

This approach

- groups by `mkt`
- loops through `mdl` within each `mkt`,
- subsets `pr` to drop values which do *not* belong to the actual value of `mdl`
- before computing `mean()` directly.

*Caveat concerning performance*: Although the code essentially is a *one-liner* it does not imply it is the fastest.